# Random alert text and pop up only once

Tags: cookies, random, popup, alert

I'm try to write up code that will allow me to create a message with text that randomly displays one of three messages. In addition, this message will appear as an alert after you click a button. I now want to also program the button so it will only appear once per user. I've been able to make the random text part work, but not the one-time pop up feature. Let me know what I should do! Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Random thingy</title>

<script language type="text/javascript">
<!--

function getMessage() {
var ar = new Array(20)
ar[0] = "your assignment will be GRADED"
ar[1] = "your assignment will be UNGRADED"
ar[2] = "your assignment will be FUN"
// add as many more that you can stand but make
// sure you update the value '7' in the alert box
var now = new Date()
var sec = now.getSeconds()
alert("Your Grading Scheme:\n\n" + ar[sec % 3])

}


<!-- Begin
var expDays = 1; // number of days the cookie should last

var page = "only-popup-once.html";
var windowprops = "width=300,height=200,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes";

function GetCookie (name) {
var arg = name + "=";
var alen = arg.length;
var clen = document.cookie.length;
var i = 0;
while (i < clen) {
var j = i + alen;
if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
return getCookieVal (j);
i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
if (i == 0) break;
}
return null;
}
function SetCookie (name, value) {
var argv = SetCookie.arguments;
var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;
var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) +
((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +
((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +
((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
}
function DeleteCookie (name) {
var exp = new Date();
exp.setTime (exp.getTime() - 1);
var cval = GetCookie (name);
document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
}
var exp = new Date();
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));
function amt(){
var count = GetCookie('count')
if(count == null) {
SetCookie('count','1')
return 1
}
else {
var newcount = parseInt(count) + 1;
DeleteCookie('count')
SetCookie('count',newcount,exp)
return count
   }
}
function getCookieVal(offset) {
var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
if (endstr == -1)
endstr = document.cookie.length;
return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}

function checkCount() {
var count = GetCookie('count');
if (count == null) {
count=1;
SetCookie('count', count, exp);

alert('MESSAGE');

}
else {
count++;
SetCookie('count', count, exp);
   }
}


//  End -->

</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="getMessage(); checkCount()">
<form>
<input type="button" name="again" value="Your Self-Assessment Grading Scheme. Click To Find Out." onClick="getMessage()">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```